# Executable file shows up as "Link to symbolic link" in Ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, exe, file-type

[image: winload.exe shows up as an "executable" but Utilman and every other executable shows up as a "link to symbolic link"]

winload.exe shows up as an "executable" but Utilman.exe and every other executable shows up as a "link to symbolic link"

[image]

I cant rename or edit these exe files, which appear as "link to symbolic link"

Answer (score 0):

Notice the size of that Utilman.exe is 26 bytes, it does seem to be a symlink or a windows shortcut. The real exe is about 80KB

Either the files are wrong or not properly mounted.
How did you mount that partition?  Is that ntfs or some virtualization sharing folders?

Comment: I did "mount -o rw /dev/sda2 /mnt"

Comment: Do you have the ntfs-3g package installed?
I would try getting the latests ntfs-3g and mounting again